# Embedding the Lighten Css Feature to Jsx/React

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I currently use the following syntax to embed a state color to jsx.

```
 <div className="preview-box" style={{backgroundColor:this.state.color}}>
```

Is there a way to use the lighten feature in css to do something like this?

```
 <div className="preview-box" style={{backgroundColor: lighten(this.state.color, 15%)}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SCSS` to get `backgroundColor: lighten(this.state.color, 15%)`

css part

```
$awesome-blue: #2196F3;
$width: 100%;
$height: 500px;

    .box {
      background: lighten($awesome-blue, 10%); /* As your need */
      width: $width;
      height:$height;
      display:flex;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:center;
    }
```

I posted just an example to how it's work may be it will help you

**[Working fiddle with scss](https://jsfiddle.net/0zvfvm6q/31/)**