# Using the css lighten and darken feature in JSX

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have currently have a hex value on the frontend that I need to lighten and darken with inline styling. I'm currently attempting to use the css `lighten` and `darken` feature like so,

```
style={{ backgroundColor: lighten(color, 10 %)}}>
```

but jsx does not like this.
Is there another way to do this? In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512011/embedding-the-lighten-css-feature-to-jsx-react) the person suggested using scss but I can't hard code the value into css because I'm fetching it from a database.

Comment: CSS has no such feature.  You're probably thinking about LESS.

Comment: the JavaScript library [color](https://github.com/Qix-/color) also has a `lighten` feature that may work for you

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe CSS have lighter and darker methods.

Hexdecimal is a 16 based number, ABCDEF corresponds to 11,12,13,14,15,16. For example AA would be 11*11 and FF would be 16*16, minus 1 for 0.

Hexdecimal color codes are 3 numbers, for example white #FFFFFF(ff,ff,ff) would be: 16*16=256th number, or 255 (0 is the first number).

The darker the higher the number. Which means... white is the darkest color and black is the lightest color.

Once you have your hexdecimal color value:

```
var red = parseInt(hexdecimal[1] + hexdecimal[2],16);
var green = parseInt(hexdecimal[3] + hexdecimal[4],16);
var blue = parseInt(hexdecimal[5] + hexdecimal[6], 16);
```

then just add to the color value if you want lighter and subtract for darker.

Here is a quick fiddle I just made:
https://jsfiddle.net/3b57L8ss/

Comment: the lighten/darken are less features.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate in HSL format and edit Lightness and Saturation.
Ready solution: https://github.com/degtyarev-artyom/lightness-saturation-css-in-js